# php dom parser get li palintext

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, domparser

i have html like this:

```
<li>
    TEXT       <---- GET THIS TEXT
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>aa</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to get "TEXT" in li element, but then i try get li element I get all elements... 
This is my code:

```
$html = str_get_html('<li>TEXT<ul><li>a</li><li>aa</li></ul></li>');
echo $html->find('li', 0)->plaintext
```

output:
TEXTaaa

but I need get only TEXT. And I can't add id or or something else

Comment: What parser are you using, link?

Comment: this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Fixed the code, please remember to mark as answer for future users (and me).

Answer (score 0):

Each part before/after a node is a textnode, so you just need to get the first childnode:

`$foo->firstChild->textContent;`

I'm assuming Simple HTML Dom implements DOMDocument...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!  What you needed was to grab the first textnode:

```
<?php

require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = str_get_html('<li>TEXT<ul><li>a</li><li>aa</li></ul></li>');
echo $html->find('li text', 0)->plaintext;

?>
```

Comment: OK, another example:
$html = str_get_html('<li>TEXT<a href="">b</a><ul><li>a</li><li>aa</li></ul></li>');
echo $html->find('li', 0)->first_child()->plaintext;
now I get "b" how get "TEST" in this situation?

Comment: You simply look at the next text node:  echo $html->find('li text', 1)->plaintext;

Answer (score -1):

OK, another example:

```
$html = str_get_html('<li>TEXT<a href="">b</a><ul><li>a</li><li>aa</li></ul></li>');
echo $html->find('li', 0)->first_child()->plaintext;
```

now I get "b" how get "TEST" in this situation?

Comment: You simply look at the next text node: echo $html->find('li text', 1)->plaintext;

Comment: If you still want TEST, then use the same query.  If you want 'b', then use echo $html->find('li text', 1)->plaintext;